# change comma dot into comma

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, input

I'm building an application in PHP using CodeIgniter,

```
<td><input name="amount1" class="form-control" type="number" value="0" onchange="calculateRow(1)" step="any"  /></td>
<td><input name="salesprice1" class="form-control" type="number" value="0.00" onchange="calculateRow(1)" step="any" /></td>
<td><input name="discount1" class="form-control" type="number" value="0" onchange="calculateRow(1)" /></td>
```

The *salesprice* is a decimal number, but you need to use a comma (,) and a dot (.) is not a legit character according to the number input. Is there a way to make the input work correctly using a dot instead of a comma?

Comment: Not sure why you've tagged PHP in this, it's clearly a client side issue.

Comment: So, do  you wish to allow users to type out commas in the input, or do want to automatically fill in the input's value with a string number that contains commas?

Comment: @JTempelman check it out https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/

Answer (score 0):

You can format your (change the decimal point to a comma) display with `number_format`

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

Read more in the docs : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.number-format.php

Comment: His input will be invalid and won't be able to submit after. Maybe php isn't the correct solution to this.

Comment: I though he wanted to use PHP to format the display, but I don't know really where the transformation is needed, I should asked for more details before pointing out how to do the format!